# Customize/Decorate console.log under Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I want to decorate the output of `console.log` under `Node.js` like following codes

```
var console = {
    log: function(text) {
         global.console.log('Test: ' + text);
    }
};

console.log('custom console is here');
```

Output:

`Test: custom console is here`

However, if I remove the `var` before the variable `console`,

```
console = {
    log: function(text) {
         global.console.log('Test: ' + text);
    }
};

console.log('custom console is here');
```

The output will be

`custom console is here`

I know the `console` will become the global variable when the `var` is deleted. Based my understanding, it will override the `global.console`, but it seems not. **Why the `global.console` cannot be override?**

The second question: **Is there any better way to custom console.log?**

Comment: I think you have to define it explicitly as: `global.console = ..`, not `console = ..`

Comment: 1. Use util.log if you want a better log. 2. the way you Are taking arguments is bad for what you want, you can only log 1 argument now, while console.log takes as many as specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the `global.console` cannot be override?

Because it is an accessor property with [only a  getter](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/08166cb99a880cdb6a61d3c1ff4765144cd81451/src/node.js#L210-L212) (which loads the [`console` module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js)).
Try strict mode and your assignment will throw.

It can be overridden by using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), but that's a very bad idea, as many modules depend on it.

> Is there any better way to custom `console.log`?

No, a `console` variable that is local to your module seems to be the best idea.

Of course you can improve your implementation, e.g. to deal with multiple arguments correctly, to be an actual `Console` instance (with all methods), or to be available via `require("my-console.js")` so that you can use it in multiple modules.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, it it not a very good idea to override the `console.log` function, because many modules depend on it.

Besides this, in your code you set the console variable to a completely new object with only the function `log` and this function can only handle 1 argument, while `console.log` can handle multiple arguments.

If you really want to override the function, try something like this instead:

```
function decorateLog(string) {
    var originalFunc = console.log;
    console.log = function(){
      originalFunc.apply(console, [string].concat([].slice.call(arguments)))
    }
}

decorateLog('Test:')

console.log('custom console is here'); //=> Test: custom console is here
console.log('foo', 'bar'); //=> Test: foo bar
```

But if you just need a better debug log, try the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) package.